# nginx rewrite wildcard not found path

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm trying to convert an Apache .htaccess config to nginx. The previous setup has a ton of redirects. Most of these seem to work out though I'm stuck on this one:

I have a path `/support/` that has an index with content I want, so that works just fine. I have a list of various `/support/all/types/of/things` that are going to other domains–these also seem to work fine. However, I also have need of a `/support/not-something-from-above` to redirect to a particular domain.

Right now I have a location block filled with rewrites like so:

```
location /support {
    rewrite /article/229/?$ https://something.com/entries/2180 redirect;
    rewrite /another/?$ https://something.com/elsewhere redirect;
    rewrite /.*$ https://what-i-want.com redirect;
}
```

There are many more rewrites in that block but the idea is to match various paths under support, and where they don't line up, send them to that last domain. All the while, preserving the `/support/` url to be my hosted index.html

I have tried:

```
rewrite /\w+$ https://what-i-want.com redirect;
rewrite /.+$ https://what-i-want.com redirect;
```

I've moved it to it's own location block specifically under /support/, tried regex matching, and I'm still stumped.

For reference, the .htaccess looked like this

```
RewriteRule ^support/dynamic/?$ https://something.com/entries/2180 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^support/toolbar/?$ https://something.com/elsewhere [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^support/.+$ https://what-i-want.com/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expressions are not specific enough. For example `/.+$` matches `/support`.

You could use a `rewrite...break` to terminate rewrite processing. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details. For example:

```
location /support/ {
    ...
    rewrite ^/support/$ /support/index.html break;
    return 302 https://what-i-want.com;
}
```

Alternatively, use an exact match location to take certain URIs out of the `location /support/` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more. For example:

```
location /support/ {
    ...
}
location = /support/ {
    index index.html;
}
location = /support/index.html {
}
```